# Searching for movie similar to Children of Men

Tags: story-identification

I saw a movie [maybe a short film or TV episode] where the world was undergoing some kind of epidemic - where women couldn't have healthy babies anymore. They weren't sterile, they just had miscarriages, or monstrous looking preemie mutated babies that never lived for more than a few hours - until one woman gets pregnant and carries her baby further than anyone else. The government detains her and keeps her in a lab for most of the 2nd trimester. She breaks out after being told they will 'mate her' and her husband with other partners in order to see if they can force more 'healthy baby possibilities'. The Government wants to study the couple. They escape and find a refugee camp in the woods with children of all ages and people who want to help. I thought it was called 'the black rain' but I guess I'm wrong because nothing pops up for that... It is a pretty creepy movie. I want to say it was from the late 90s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All of your plot points appear to match an episode of *The Outer Limits* called ["Dark Rain" (1997)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Rain_%28The_Outer_Limits%29). It's plot was inspired by the P. D. James novel [*The Children of Men* (1992)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Children_of_Men) (which obviously led to the later film adaptation [*Children of Men* (2006)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_Men)).

Comment: I think you nailed it.  Outer Limits was my first thought on this as well.